# Symfony2 Doctrine - ILIKE clause for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently using symfony2, doctrine 2.3 and PostgreSQL 9. I've been searching for a couple of hours now to see HOW on earth do I do a `ILIKE` select with `QueryBuilder`.

It seems they only have `LIKE`. In my situation, though, I'm searching case-insensitive. 
How on earth is it done?

```
// -- this is the "like";
$search = 'user';
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('users');
$query->where($query->expr()->like('users.username', $query->expr()->literal('%:username%')))->setParameter(':username', $search);


// -- this is where I get "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 86: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'ILIKE'
$search = 'user';
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('users');
$query->where('users.username ILIKE :username')->setParameter(':username', $search);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about Symfony, but you can substitute

```
a ILIKE b
```

with

```
lower(a) LIKE lower(b)
```

You could also try the operator `~~*`, which is a synonym for `ILIKE`
It has slightly lower operator precedence, so you might need parenthesis for concatenated strings where you wouldn't with `ILIKE`

```
a ILIKE b || c
```

becomes

```
a ~~* (b || c)
```

[The manual about pattern matching, starting with `LIKE` / `ILIKE`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

I think this guy had the same problem and got an answer:
http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=40424

Obviously, you can extend Symfony2 with SQL vendor specific functions:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

I am not a fan of ORMs and frameworks butchering the rich functionality of Postgres just to stay "portable" (which hardly ever works).

Comment: The `lower(a)/lower(b)` is working in the query itself but it's not in doctrine for some reason. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: @tftd: My expertise is with PostgreSQL. But I think I found something for you.

Comment: Yeah.. I also don't like the ORMs that are meant to be "portable". That never works as planned! Thanks for the help, the solution from symfony-project works with a bit of tuning.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me (Symfony2 + Doctrine 2)

```
$qq = 'SELECT x FROM MyBundle:X x WHERE LOWER(x.y) LIKE :y';
$q = $em->createQuery($qq)->setParameter(':y', strtolower('%' . $filter . '%'));
$result = $q->getResult();
```

Comment: It works but it is slow when querying big amount of records

Comment: It does not hit index when using LOWER

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, we still do not have the ability to create custom comparison operators...

But we can create a custom function in which we implement the comparison.

Our DQL query well look like this:

```
SELECT q FROM App\Entity\Customer q WHERE ILIKE(q.name, :name) = true
```

The class describing the ILIKE function will look like this:

```
class ILike extends FunctionNode
{
    /** @var Node */
    protected $field;
    /** @var Node */
    protected $query;

    /**
     * @param Parser $parser
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->field = $parser->StringExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->query = $parser->StringExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    /**
     * @param SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ASTException
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return '(' . $this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ' ILIKE ' . $this->query->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

The resulting SQL will look like this:

```
SELECT c0_.id AS id_0,
       c0_.name AS name_1,
FROM customer c0_
WHERE (c0_.name ILIKE 'paramvalue') = true
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I am aware, search queries in Symfony2 (at least when using Doctrine) are **case in-sensitive**. As noted in [the Doctrine QL docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

> DQL is case in-sensitive, except for namespace, class and field names, which are case sensitive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're referring to the column names used in the query rather than the values you're searching i.e. username=MyUser will not return the same result as username=myusername. Anyway, I overcome this problem by either using the selected answer.